# Disable Android USB Auto-Detect

Tags: usb, 4.2-jelly-bean

I have an android 4.2 embedded system.
When I connect a USB cool-disk to my device's USB port, it recognizes the cool-disk and works just fine.
But then the LED light on my connected cool-disk keeps flashing and I've learned to believe that the reason is that the USB Auto-Detection has not stopped on the USB port.

Do you know any android process that I can kill, in order to stop auto-detection on the USB port?

Any other idea to fix that flashing LED is much appreciated.

Comment: It's rather doubtful that what you suspect is actually the case.  Does the USB drive behave differently when connected to a typical desktop system?

Comment: @ChrisStratton: yes, normally it doesn't keep flashing.